# Showing a set is bounded and closed.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

For  $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n - n $ with $x_i \geq 0 $ for all $i$.

I want to show that $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) = 0 \} $ is compact.

### My try

Obviously, by continuity of $f$ and since $\{0 \}$ is closed, then $A = f^{-1}( \{ 0 \} ) $ is closed. But, how can I show $A$ is bounded? Do we need the condition that $x_i \geq 0$ for $A$ to be bounded?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of $f$ if one of the inputs is negative. This is kind of important, because when you say $\{x\in\mathbb R^n:f(x)=0\}$ you're specifying that we apply $f$ to _every_ point in $\mathbb R^n$ to find out whether it is in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean that the $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed. Be careful because that is not what you wrote.

For a fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$, rewrite $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ as $x_1+\ldots+x_n = n$. So you are trying to show that the set of positive $n$-tuples that sum to $n$ is bounded. What is the largest any of the $x_i$ could possibly be?

Comment: At most $n$ ???